# CSS change stops mouseover/hover

Tags: javascript, css, button

I have seen similar queries but none which fits my issue.

I have some code which removes some CSS rules for a button and then later writes them back in, in exactly the same place so to all intents and purposes the state of the CSS is unchanged. Originally mouseover worked and changed the button image as it should. I detect no difference in the CSS in Firebug but the mouseover no longer works and doesn't change the button image. The CSS is in exactly the same position as it was originally and there is no change to it.

If in Firebug I alter anything in the CSS then the problem rectifies immediately. Even just changing 0px to 0px in a 'background-position' parameter for the normal sprite rule and nothing else everything is then as it should be. It seems as though something somewhere needs to be forcibly refreshed?

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

If it should occur that removing and putting back CSS is rather pointless, it is in an attempt to isolate a similar niggle in a more useful scenario.

I have just checked out what happens when I Zap all the CSS and restore and everything works fine.

Not just in FFox either.

Thanks.

John B

Comment: Can you show some source code?

Comment: can you please share your code, I suspect it may be because of bind vs live/on problem..